# Como adicionar vários elementos dentro da função html() do jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte trecho:

```
$('#div').html();
```

Preciso adicionar algumas `div` dentro dessa `div`, mas eu não sei como, pois se eu tentar fazer dessa forma dá erro:

**NOTEM O SINAL DE ADIÇÃO PARA A CONCATENAÇÃO**

```
$('#div').html($('<div>',{id: 'divteste', class: 'divteste'}).html('DIV 1') + $('<div>', {id: 'div2', class: 'teste2'}).html('DIV 2'));
```

A questão é: Como eu concateno a adição de várias `div` dentro de uma função `html()` do `jQuery`?

Comment: Ja tentou com .append()?

Comment: Já tentei, só que o problema não é criar o elemento em si, e sim criar vários elementos dentro do html()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse método só aceita uma string com argumento. Creio você tenha recebido um erro de parseHTML.
Você poderia montar uma string dessa forma:

```
var str = "";
str += "<div id='meuId'>;
str += "<div class='minhaClasse'></div><!-- /.minhaClasse -->";
str += "</div><!-- /#meuId -->";

$("elemento").html(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar elementos DOM com a ajuda do `$.html()` da mesma forma que faria com o `element.innerHTML`, concatenando scripts, porém este método é bastante ineficiente.

```js
var div1 = $('#div1');
div1.html("");
div1.html(div1.html() + $('<div>', {id: 'trecho11', class: 'divteste' }).html('DIV 1.1').wrapAll('<div>').parent().html());
div1.html(div1.html() + $('<div>', {id: 'trecho12', class: 'divteste' }).html('DIV 1.2').wrapAll('<div>').parent().html());

var div2 = $('#div2');
div2.html("");
div2.html(div2.html() + '<div id="trecho21" class="divteste">DIV 2.1</div>');
div2.html(div2.html() + '<div id="trecho22" class="divteste">DIV 2.2</div>');

var div3 = document.querySelector('#div3');
div3.innerHTML = "";
div3.innerHTML += '<div id="trecho31" class="divteste">DIV 3.1</div>';
div3.innerHTML += '<div id="trecho32" class="divteste">DIV 3.2</div>';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">

</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
<div id="div3">

</div>
```

agora uma forma mais otimizada para fazer o mesmo.:

```js
var div1 = $('#div1');
div1.empty("");
div1.append($('<div>', {id: 'trecho11', class: 'divteste' }).html('DIV 1.1'));
div1.append($('<div>', {id: 'trecho12', class: 'divteste' }).html('DIV 1.2'));

var createBloco = function (id, conteudo) {
  var bloco = document.createElement('div');
  bloco.id = id;
  bloco.classList.add('divteste');
  bloco.textContent = conteudo;
  return bloco;
};

var div2 = document.querySelector('#div2');
while (div2.firstChild) div2.removeChild(div2.firstChild);
div2.appendChild(createBloco('trecho21', 'DIV 2.1'));
div2.appendChild(createBloco('trecho21', 'DIV 2.1'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  Old
</div>
<div id="div2">
  Old
</div>
```

for fim uma alternativa com html que pode vir a ser um pouco mais elegante.:

```js
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#tmpl').html());
var html = tmpl([ 'DIV 1', 'DIV 2','DIV 3' ]);
$('#div1').html(html);

var source = document.querySelector('#tmpl').textContent;
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html = tmpl([ 'DIV 1', 'DIV 2','DIV 3' ]);
document.querySelector('#div2').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.js"></script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each this}}
  <div id="elem{{@index}}" class="divteste">
    {{this}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No lugar do html(); usa o append() do jquery confome o exemplo abaixo, criei duas divs separadas e inseri as 2 na mesma com o append, basta adaptar ao teu método

```js
var div1 = "<div>nada</div>";
var div2 = "<div>nada denovo</div>";

$("#teste").append(div1);
$("#teste").append(div2);

alert($("#teste").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="teste"></div>
```